# How would multiple races impact space faring?

Tags: society, races

Assuming I have elves and humans both evolved on my world:

The United Federal Sapients is a government similar to the US government with similar systems in place (e.g. Congress, Senate, President, Supreme Court). It is interracial---meaning both elves and humans live as equals. The tech level is 1970-ish.

Assuming otherwise my planet is much like Earth, how might the space program of my multi-race civilization develop in 30 years? Would the possible conflict between races effect my national space program?

**EDIT:**

The elves have slight physical differences. They diverged from our evolutionary tree and evolved to have no body hair. They are unable to have children with humans except in rare (1 in ten million) instances and the resulting offspring are infertile.

Unlike most countries where Elves and Humans are constantly fighting, the UFS has total equality withe even the government of mixed species. Elves cannot reproduce until they are at least 20 years old and live to be 120-150.

To clarify, I am looking for societal impacts that could either effect the space program directly or indirectly.

**So, would there be more conflict (than, say, black and white), at least to the level that it would effect the space program? Another way to word it would be, how would the conflict be different than modern racial tension in America and how could this (or would it?) effect space travel?**

**EDIT2:**

Elves have superior strength but it takes longer for them to mature than humans. The population ration is about 60/50 (Humans to Elves). Earlier (150-200 years) in the history of this world a civil war (similar to the American Civil War) was fought to end the legality forced sexual abuse of elven women by human males. The side fighting to end this abuse won the war, so this is a possible mode of conflict.

Many wars pre-UFS have been fought between elves and humans to determine resource ownership and it is possible that some hatred might still exist.

Elves also have a stronger bone structure and their vital organs are able to repair themselves easily when exposed to radiation that would give humans cancer. The elves are the ones who invented space technology and this was quickly adapted and perfected (to 1970 levels) by humanity. The world in question has a habitable moon and the races want to set up research bases on it studying the effects of reduced gravity on Flora and Fauna (both native moon and 'Earth' life).

Humans and Elves interact (mostly) on equal terms, although racial (or would it be species?) discrimination is not outlawed and many Elves and Humans own shops not permitting each other service. Restrooms are separate and many other 1970ish bans.

The exact details of the mission are:

- 6 Human crew.
- 8 Elf crew.

The unstated political goal of the mission is to discourage fighting between races and show that they can both coexist peacefully.

Comment: Seems very broad and the description is only vaguely related to the question title - can you revise and clarify?

Comment: I am actually working on it now.

Comment: Still seems broad.

Comment: @bowlturner i don't think so but if you feel need to close go ahead.

Comment: You should start by explaining the differences between elves and human. Otherwise, you could be as well talking of a planet with men and women, or black people and white people, and asking the same question.

Comment: @SJuan76 I made suggested edits.

Comment: I think your edits were a good start, but not enough.  We still lack an understanding of the culture enough to give a valid answer.  If the culture is fully integrated and everyone is equal then no, race shouldn't matter at all unless one race is better suited for space travel.  If the culture is not fully equal then yes, racial division will be an issue.  However, I lack knowledge about what racial division may currently exist to elaborate on how much or what kind of issues will occur.  In short we need to know how elves and humans interact currently and what tensions may exist.

Comment: Encouragement for editing. But, you only added that they are hairless. Explain why they might be different for this endeavour!

Comment: @dsollen I have added some detail. If you need further clarification drop another comment.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan Thank you, I think that's sufficient information to write useful answers, I've voted to reopen.  I may take a shot at answering this late too, for now I really need to get back to work :)

Comment: @JDługosz I made some edits.

Answer (score 0):

Why US government based? The US government is known to be inherently unstable and to lead to gridlock and in most nations where it exists or has existed civil war and overthrow of the government. Parliamentary systems, which are similar to the US but with significant differences may work better.

In a US style system the biggest thing is if your elves are in Senate and Congress and if they have any term limits and if they have longer life spans than humans. Any magic is just another technology; and presidential politics are presidential politics and somewhat overblown (compare SLS and Orion to Constellation and then tell me that Obama canceling Constellation actually had a significant impact on what the Senators in charge wanted to have happen). If the Elves live a long time and can serve in Congress then A) Congress will have a relatively disproportionate number of Elves relative to Humans (there may be absolutely more Humans in congress via population demographics) and B) This could lead to greater stability in the space program budget and missions, which would lead to some more actually getting done.

Now as for how much more actually getting done, that really depends on is there a USSR-type threat to compete against so that space is seen as a military priority? Is there something like the Outer Space Treaty that prevents the ownership and commercialization (arguably) of space? What is the contract structure of the space program? Is it done primarily as a jobs program? Does one race have a monopoly on the contracts or are they spread across everyone? Or are missions done in some bidding process, say for example the elves primarily run the science organization that designs mission parameters and sets contracts for primarily human companies to fulfill on a competitive basis, perhaps.

It is a pretty vague question.